# Where does "/folder1/folder2/file.ext" save to in Python?

Tags: python, file, path, directory

I know there must be a really obvious answer, but it eludes me. Where does "/folder1/folder2/file.ext" save to in Python? In some code I thought (incorrectly) that it would save the file to a relative path, but when I checked folder2 it wasn't there. However, it seemed to still take up the hard disk space. I did a search on my hard drive and couldn't find the file. Where did it go? Again, I'm aware that there must be a really obvious answer out there, but I am just learning to code.

Comment: Are you running on Windows, Linux or OSX?

Comment: Paths that start with a `/` are absolute paths, not relative. (Except on Windows, where they're only absolute to the current working drive.)

Comment: But this isn't really a Python question. Python treats paths the same way almost every other program in the universe does. If you don't understand what paths mean on your platform, that's probably a question for Super User, not Stack Overflow, and a question about your platform, not about Python.

Comment: @abarnert I'm using Windows, so if the current working drive is C, then the file would be in C:/folder1/folder2/ ? I'll make sure to post to SuperUser in the future with issues like this - thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @amateur3057 Exactly right. (Of course Windows usually uses backslashes rather than slashes as separators in paths, but most programs—including Python—allow you to use slashes instead. Because `/` isn't a valid character within a Windows filename, this doesn't cause any ambiguity.)

Comment: Depends where you run the `.py` from. Use `os.getcwd()` to find out where you are on the system. If you run a file from the directory, then your current working drive (e.g. `cwd`) is that directory. It should always be `[cwd]/folder1/folder2/file.ext`.

Comment: @pstatix Is there a functional difference between "/folder1/folder2/" and "./folder1/folder2/" then (note the beginning ".")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would read about the [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module and the [module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

I opened the IDLE 3.7.0 on my Windows 10 machine and did the following:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Python37'
>>> os.path.abspath('./folder1')
'C:\\Python37\\folder1'
```

Windows expands the `.` to represent the current working drive, thus wherever the interpreter is looking is where your folders will reside.

In the links, it talks about how [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) works (in short the directory containing the current script is placed at the front of it [e.g. the current working directory] for searching).

So, in short, either run your script directly from the directory or call `os.chdir('/your/desired/path')`.